# Using SitecoreUser.Profile with Forms Authentication

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We use sitecore to manage our registered users (extranet domain) and when creating new virtual users we give it an email using the `Profile.Email` property and then call the `Profile.Save()` method.
Another property somewhere else reads the `userProfile.Email`, everything is fine at the beginning. 
Plus we use Forms authentication with the remember me feature.
The problem is when we close the browser and reopen it `Sitecore.Context.User` contains info about the actual user who clicked remember me but the `User.Profile` always has the Email null.
I tried `Reload()` and `initialize()` they don't work. I also tried getting the user again via the username (`User.FromName()`) but the returned user object also doesn't have the Profile Email.

What is being done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is one very important remark in [Security API Cookbook](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/security_api_cookbook_sc60_and_later-a4.pdf). It is related to Sitecore 6 but as far as I know it should work with Sitecore 8 as there was no important changes in Security model. It worked for [Sitecore 7](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-allow-virtual-user-to-browse-on.html).

> **Important** You must log in a virtual user only after you assign *Roles* and *Profile* properties to them. The *Roles and Profile* properties that are assigned after logging in are lost upon subsequent request.

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user =
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(@"domain\user"
, true);
if (user != null)
{
 string domainRole = @"domain\role";
 if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
 {
 user.Roles.Add(Role.FromName(domainRole));
 }

 user.Profile.Email = "user@domain.com";
 user.Profile[“Custom Property”] = “Custom Value”;
 user.Profile.Save();
 Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(user);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your excellent answer but the Profile data doesn't get lost upon subsequent requests (we use success = AuthenticationManager.Login(sitecoreVirtualUser.Name, persist)) after filling Profile.Email and saving it. the data only gets lost after starting a new session after closing the browser, when Sitecore and ASP.NET authentication try to create a new session from the ASPXAUTH cookie. But then the Email doesn't get filled. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not the one who implemented this originally. How can I make sure?

Comment: Open your showconfig.aspx  and look for switchingProviders section

Comment: Under SwitchingProviders there is a <profile> tag with only the following: <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" ignoredDomains=""/>